# How to remove white space gap between body content and footer?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

After researching this topic a bit, I've found that this is a fairly common question to ask, but a solution varies depending on the theme. I contact my theme's developers, but have not received a response.

I've looked through my theme's CSS and haven't been able to find how or where to get rid of this white space gap between the body content and my footer.

[Here is a screenshot of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBzID.jpg) (Please note: this is a screenshot of a preview; it isn't actually live). My website is: https://dental.keystoneindustries.com/

Is there a line of CSS I need to edit/remove/add? If so, where? CSS posted below.

```
#languageSelector {
display: none;
}

/*Language selector*/

div#all-site-wrapper.hfeed.site div.OneLinkShow.OneLinkKeepLinks {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: auto;
right: auto;
z-index: 100000;
}

div#all-site-wrapper.hfeed.site div.OneLinkShow.OneLinkKeepLinks p {
max-width: 1170px;
width: auto;
padding: 15px 15px 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.wpr_hazzard_img {
width: auto !important;
display: block;
}

.wpr_hazzard_img_inline {
width: auto !important;
display: inline-block !important;
}

.wpr_message_box {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
padding: 0 20px;
vertical-align: top;
background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
border: 3px solid black;
border-radius: 0;
color: black;
}

.group_table .woocommerce .quantity, .woocommerce-page .quantity{
width: 50px !important;
display: inline-block;
float: left !important;
}
.group_table .wpr_tooltip_js{
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#all-site-wrapper .iv-layout.header .login-ajax .trigger {
font-size: 13px;
}


.header-right-area {
margin-top:12px;
}
.live-search .iv-layout.header .inner-form {
padding: 14px;
}
.live-search {
position: relative;
}
.live-search .trigger {
display: none;
}
.live-search .inner-wrapper {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
position: static;
}

#all-site-wrapper .live-search:not(.search-top-style):not(.search-full-screen-              alt-style):not(.search-full-screen-style) .inner-wrapper:after,
#all-site-wrapper .live-search:not(.search-top-style):not(.search-full-screen-    alt-style):not(.search-full-screen-style) .inner-wrapper:before {
display: none;
}
.live-search .inner-wrapper {
width: 260px;
border: 0 none;
}
#all-site-wrapper .live-search .inner-form {
padding: 0;
}

.classic-right-area .wpr-fix .iv-module {
margin-left: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.classic-right-area {
    min-height: 200px;
}
.classic-right-area .header-right-area {
    position: relative;
}

#all-site-wrapper .classic-right-area .wpr-fix .iv-module {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#all-site-wrapper .wpr-fix {
    width: auto;
}
#all-site-wrapper .login-ajax {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#all-site-wrapper .woo-cart {
    margin-top: 4px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
#all-site-wrapper .wpr-fix .iv-module {
    display: block;
}
#all-site-wrapper .wpr-fix {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#all-site-wrapper .login-ajax .inner-wrapper {
    left: 0;
}
#all-site-wrapper .login-ajax .inner-wrapper:before {
    left: 31px;
}
#all-site-wrapper .login-ajax .inner-wrapper:after {
    left: 32px;
}
#all-site-wrapper .classic-right-area .custom-text {
    display: none !important;
}
#all-site-wrapper .wpr-fix .live-search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.wpr-spacer {
    height: 130px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#all-site-wrapper .wpr-fix .live-search {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    position: static;
    float: none;
}
#all-site-wrapper .wpr-fix .login-ajax {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 25%;
    width: 200px;
}
#all-site-wrapper .wpr-fix .woo-cart {
    position: absolute;
    left: 41%;
    top: 20px;
    width: 250px;
}
#all-site-wrapper .logo img {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#all-site-wrapper .header-left-area {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 24%;
}
#all-site-wrapper .header-left-area .logo {
    margin: 35px 0 0px;
}


#all-site-wrapper .live-search .inner-form {
    margin-top: -46px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
#all-site-wrapper .wpr-fix .login-ajax {
    left: 22%;
}
}

@media (max-width: 478px) {
#all-site-wrapper .wpr-fix .login-ajax {
    left: 0;
    width: 80px;
}
#all-site-wrapper .wpr-fix .woo-cart {
    left: 24%;
    width: auto;
}

#all-site-wrapper .classic-right-area .wpr-fix .iv-module.live-search {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15%;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
}

.live-search .inner-wrapper {
    width: 170px;
    border: 0 none;
}

.wpr-spacer {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.wpr-fix {
    margin-top: 0;
}

div#all-site-wrapper.hfeed.site div.OneLinkShow.OneLinkKeepLinks p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
}

#all-site-wrapper .header-left-area .logo {
    margin: 5px 0 0;
}

.classic-right-area .menu-area-wrapper {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.classic-right-area {
    min-height: 130px;
}

.classic-right-area.stuck {
    min-height: inherit;
}

.classic-right-area.stuck .container {
    display: block !important;
}

.classic-right-area.stuck .container .header-left-area .logo {
    margin: 15px auto !important;
}

.classic-right-area.stuck .container .header-left-area .logo .logo-normal {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.classic-right-area.stuck .container .wpr-fix {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have elements with the class `.ivan-custom-wrapper` which have a `margin-bottom: 45px;` which is causing the white space. Either remove that margin completely or change it to a `margin-top` and then zero out the margin on the first instance of that element.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm not finding the `.ivan-custom-wrapper` class in the CSS above though - am I not looking in the right place for this? I'm getting this CSS from the Stylesheet in Editor.

Comment: I'm not sure which file it's in since you are using a minifier that is combining all of your CSS files. But it's in one of them, not the main CSS file.